# C# attribute that can only be on a method within a class with another attribute

Tags: c#, attributes, restriction

In C# is it possible to put a restriction on an attribute so that it can only be on a method within a class that has another attribute?

```
[MyClassAttribute]
class Foo
{
    [MyMethodAttribute]
    public string Bar()
}
```

Where "MyMethodAttribute" can only be inside of a class that has "MyClassAttribute".

Is that possible? If so, how can it be done?

Comment: I doubt that's possible, Attributes by themselves do nothing.

Comment: I don't know of a compile time way to achieve this. However, in `MyMethodAttribute` ctor you could, via reflection, check if a required attribute exists on the class hosting `MyMethodAttribute`.

Comment: You can write a Roslyn analyzer that verifies this at compile-time and shows an error if it violates this rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were going to try a run time validation of your method attributes, you could do something like this:

```
public abstract class ValidatableMethodAttribute : Attribute
{
    public abstract bool IsValid();
}

public class MyMethodAtt : ValidatableMethodAttribute
{
    private readonly Type _type;

    public override bool IsValid()
    {
        // Validate your class attribute type here
        return _type == typeof (MyMethodAtt);
    }

    public MyMethodAtt(Type type)
    {
        _type = type;
    }
}

[MyClassAtt]
public class Mine
{
    // This is the downside in my opinion,
    // must give compile-time type of containing class here.
    [MyMethodAtt(typeof(MyClassAtt))]
    public void MethodOne()
    {

    }
}
```

Then use reflection to find all `ValidatableMethodAttributes` in the system, and call `IsValid()` on them. This isn't very reliable and is fairly brittle, but this type of validation could achieve what you are looking for.

Alternatively pass the type of the class ( `Mine` ), then in `IsValid()` use reflection to find all Attributes on the `Mine` type.

Answer (score 1):

You maybe able to do this with PostSharp: [(see: Compile time Validation in this tutorial)](http://fgheysels.blogspot.com.au/2008/08/locking-system-with-aspect-oriented.html)

Then in your attribute, would check for the parent class with code similar to this:

```
public class MyCustomAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyCustomAttribute()
    {
        if (GetType().CustomAttributes.Count(attr => attr.AttributeType == typeof (MyCustomClassAttribute)) < 1) 
        {
             throw new Exception("Needs parent attribute") //Insert Postsharp method of raising compile time error here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this on user defined attributes. But I believe the compiler has such mechanism, the built-in `FieldOffsetAttribute` uses this.

```
struct MyStruct
{
    [FieldOffset(1)]    //compile error, StructLayoutAttribute is required
    private int _num;
}
```

**EDIT** I think it's doable if you inject the building process, using something like [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/).